# Structured data for crypto and games?

Tags: structured-data

What would be the best structured data to use to inform gamers about our P2E Games, Crypto News and NFT Games lists?

Comment: Are you trying to get a rich snippet in the search results?  There isn't a lot of reason to use structured data unless Google uses it to show special treatment in the search results.

Comment: Respectfully, that is not true. Structured data can be used to convey meaning in a wide variety of ways.

Comment: I'm not aware of any clients that extract meaning from structured data in meaningful ways that help your site other than search engine rich snippets.  Do you have some examples?

Answer (score 1):

For your games:

`SoftwareApplication` with `GameApplication` as the value of `applicationCategory`

For your news simply use `Article`, `NewsArticle`, or `BlogPosting`

You don't need to mark up your NFT games list with JSON-LD, semantic HTML should be sufficient. I would use a `<table>` element for your lists - use your discretion as to whether you want to inline some Microdata.